# Export mysql table as xml file with table columns as attributes

Tags: mysql, xml

Consider the following table (there are three columns and two rows):

```
col1|col2|col3
row1_v1|row1_v2|row1_v3
row2_v1|row2_v2|row2_v3
...
```

When I extract the MySQL table as a XML file

```
sudo mysql --xml -u root -p testDB testTable>testTable.xml
```

the xml file is written as follows:

```
<row>
   <field name = "col1">row1_v1</field>
   <field name = "col2">row1_v2</field>
   <field name = "col3">row1_v3</field>
<row>
<row>
   <field name = "col1">row2_v1</field>
   <field name = "col2">row2_v2</field>
   <field name = "col3">row2_v3</field>
<row>
...
```

However, I want to extract the XML file as follows:

```
<row col1 = "row1_v1" col2 = "row1_v2" col3 = "row1_v3" />
<row col1 = "row2_v1" col2 = "row2_v2" col3 = "row2_v3" />
```

How can I format the output of the XML file?

Answer (score 1):

You can not customaize the xml output rules using the 'mysql --xml' option. See the reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_xml

In order to customize the output, you can do the followings:

1. Generate the xml output using the 'mysql --xml' command
2. Create a separate script that can take the 'xml output' and convert it to any cusotmizable format.